# event listener is not linked to my element properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to Javascript and I am trying to create a simple button, that when clicked will refresh the page (reload the game). I wrote the below code and when I inspect the button in Chrome, there are no event listeners attached to it.

```js
var replay = function() {
  var replayButton = getElementById('play-Again');
  replayButton.addEventListener('click', window.location.reload());
  document.getElementById('play-again').appendChild(replayButton);
}
```

```html
<button id="play-Again">Play again?</button>
```

Comment: Is the JS loaded before the element exists?

Comment: document.getElementById instead of getElementById ?

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear, but yes I have my JS script running after I declare play-again in my HTML file

Comment: You aren't calling `replay()` anywhere. Also you aren't passing a function to the event listener because you are calling `reload()` immediately

Answer (score 0):

If you want just a simple reload button, you can use this:

```
<button id="play-again" onclick="window.location.reload()">Play again?</button>
```

Otherwise: The EventListener must be executed when the js file is loaded, which it doesn't on your code because you placed it into a function that you probably never call! So you either put the EventListener outside of the function or you call the function somewhere.
Plus, the last line where you call `...appendChild(...)` doesn't seem right.

Comment: Inline JavaScript (event attributes) are generally a bad idea. JavaScript should be in a script tag, not spread about the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code, you need to give the event listener a function.  Currently your are giving it the response of calling a function, not an actual function value.  Here is revised code for your `addEventListener`

```
replayButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  window.location.reload()
});
```